# How to validate full iso date time string with Luxon

Tags: javascript, date, luxon

So what I want is to get a validation error for this iso string:

```
const dateTime = luxon.DateTime.fromISO("3");
console.log(dateTime.isValid); //true
```

I can't understand why this is a valid ISO date?
Can I accept only this format to be valid:

```
const dateTime = luxon.DateTime.fromISO("2024-03-04T19:44:41.206Z");
console.log(dateTime.isValid); //true
```

Thank you!

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans ok, how to make sure that my string is in this format "2024-03-04T19:44:41.206Z"?

Comment: beside that i think you should set up Settings.throwOnInvalid = true; in order to get errors

Comment: I spoke too soon - if I go to https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetime, open dev tools, and type ``d = luxon.DateTime.fromISO(`3`); d.isValid``, it reports `false`. So I guess the question is: are you using an up to date version of luxon?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I run tests here https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/parsing and here `isValid === true`. Yea, I see that my example works fine on your page. I might need to upgrade my luxon. But anyway on your page  `d = luxon.DateTime.fromISO("1213"); d.isValid` reports `true`. I don't like it:) I want this to be false. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: That's different, 1234 _is_ a valid ISO date. You may need to read up on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 because there's a _lot_ of valid strings covered by it that won't match what you're thinking of.

Comment: as we are using Luxon, I am trying to find the way to use this library to be able to validate JS ISO date format, there should be 25-27 symbols according to this documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Comment: As per literally that link, ISO datetime strings are _any_ string that conforms to ISO 8601. You don't get to make up a pattern and then go "that's the only valid ISO string" =) If you want a validator that checks whether a given string matches  a specific datetime format like yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss etc. .etc. then first parse it, then _convert it back to a sting that uses your format_, and then check if those are the same. Because you don't want "valid ISO datetimes", you want "valid as per our very specific much more restricted requirements", so you'll have to write some code on top.

Comment: Anyway, all examples related to `fromISO` uses this format `DateTime.fromISO('2014-08-06T13:07:04.054')`